How to access event data from AWS EventBridge that triggered a Glue Workflow?
I have an AWS Glue Workflow that is triggered by an EventBridge event, and I'm trying to access the event data inside the Glue job. I have sent Matched event, Part of matched event and Input Transformer from the EventBridge, the EventBridge gets triggered but I do not get the event object from the EventBridge in the Glue job.
Tried the following approaches:

Using $ as a placeholder in the Job Parameter for the event data from the EventBridge to the Glue job.

Using input transformers in EventBridge to map and pass the event object fields to the Glue job.


import json
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['event_data'])
event_data = json.loads(args['event_data'])
print(event_data)


can you try to add the following:

glue_client = boto3.client("glue")
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME','WORKFLOW_NAME', 'WORKFLOW_RUN_ID'])

workflow_name = args['WORKFLOW_NAME']
workflow_run_id = args['WORKFLOW_RUN_ID']

workflow_params = glue_client.get_workflow_run_properties(Name=workflow_name,RunId=workflow_run_id)
batched_events = workflow_params['aws:eventIds']

print(batched_events)


And inspect what the print statement returns.
This code is based on what is described in:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/viewing-start-event-info.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/workflow-run-properties-code.html

